# Jquery Date Picker with some dates in bold format

Tags: jquery

how can we make a date shown in bold format?

```
var events = {};
events[new Date('02/14/2011')] = new Event('Valentines Day', 'mybold');
events[new Date('02/18/2011')] = new Event('Payday', 'mybold');
    $('#calender').datepicker({
        changeMonth : true,
        changeYear : true,
        beforeShowDay : function(date) {
            var event = events[date];
            if (event) {
                return [ true, 'mybold', event.text ];
            } else {
                return [ true, '', '' ];
            }
        }
    });
.
.
.
.
<style>
.mybold>a {
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: yellow !important; 
    background-image: none !important;
}
</style>
```

It is showing the background colour as yellow but not showing the text in bold?
Thanks

Comment: see the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738293/can-you-bold-jquery-ui-datepicker-fields

Comment: I gone through it but that too is not working for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do

```
.mybold>a.ui-state-default {
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: none;
}
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/3dHWh/2/

This works because targeting an element with a class is stronger than targeting an element generally, and for this reason you were not overriding the standard ui theme (so no need for `!important` at all)